# How to achieve video streaming with spring webflux when the resource is a URL instead of a file

Tags: java, spring-boot, video-streaming, spring-webflux

I am new to spring reactive framework

I also understand how to handle  from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PEPaWFs064).

code like this

```java
    public Mono<Resource> getVideo(String videoId) {
        log.info(videoId);
        return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:video/123.mp4"));
    }
```

But now my resouces is like (http://xxxx.com/video/123.mp4) not like (classpath:videos/123.mp4, /usr/videos/123.mp4). For security reasons, I cannot directly provide the the URL to the front-end (if I do this, it can run normally).

So my question is How to use my webflux service as a proxy for this URL, or can I even use servlet instead of reactive?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have a look at spring resource base bean ```Resource``` , there is a subclass named ```UrlResource``` that could recevie the byte stream from  network ,
```Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
            try {
                return new UrlResource("http://xxxx.com/video/123.mp4");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
public Mono<Resource> getVideo(String videoId) {
    log.info(videoId);
    return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> resourceLoader.getResource(String.format("http://xxxx.com/video/123.mp4")));
}
```

Comment: first thank you for your help, I have tried this method , but I received "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource content length should be > 0", resource url can play in browser

Comment: Working fine for me make sure video should be present on following url. Typo error